# Will Wireless mouse consume more power on a perforated surface?

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse

Will the battery life of a wireless mouse be affected in anyway if used on top of a perforated aluminium surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely no, since most modern mice are optical and it doesn't matter to the mouse what the pattern on the surface is, only that there is a trackable surface. Not all mice work well with shiny surfaces and the perforations might cause *physical* wear and tear to the mice though.